# Creating matrix in loop using a function in R

Tags: r

I have a function to use in R

```
TV <- function(v1,v2) {
  write.csv(log(2 ^ (-1 / 2) * exp(-1 / 2) * beta(1 / 2, v1 / 2) / gamma(1 / 2)) - log(2 ^ (-1 / 2) * exp(-1 / 2) * beta(1 / 2, v2 / 2) / gamma(1 / 2)) + (v1 + 1) * digamma(v1 / 2 + 1 / 2) / 2 + (-1 - v2) * digamma(v2 / 2 + 1 / 2) / 2 + (-1 - v1) * digamma(v1 / 2) / 2 + (v2 + 1) * digamma(v2 / 2) / 2 + 0.5e0 * log(v1 / v2),"write.csv")
}
```

as you can see the input variables are v1 and v2.
if i give v1=1:10 and v2=1
i get single vector like this
[result for v1=1:10 and v2=1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wfSb.png)

what i need is a matrix output. for v1=1:10 to v2=1:10. i.e as 10x10 matrix.
how can i do it using R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
write.csv(outer(1:10, 1:10, FUN=function(v1,v2)log(2 ^ (-1 / 2) * exp(-1 / 2) * beta(1 / 2, v1 / 2) / gamma(1 / 2)) - 
        log(2 ^ (-1 / 2) * exp(-1 / 2) * beta(1 / 2, v2 / 2) / gamma(1 / 2)) + (v1 + 1) * digamma(v1 / 2 + 1 / 2) / 2 + 
        (-1 - v2) * digamma(v2 / 2 + 1 / 2) / 2 + (-1 - v1) * digamma(v1 / 2) / 2 + (v2 + 1) * digamma(v2 / 2) / 2 + 0.5e0 * log(v1 / v2)), 'write.csv')
```